# Jenkins pipeline script running continuously once the pull request created

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm using **github pull request builder** plugin to trigger jenkins pipeline script. At the end of pipeline script in post action, I'm pushing the results in **Compare branch** of pull request. Once the 1st job execution gets finished, next job running continuously one after another till the time pull request was kept open.

I've tried to find out what causing the job to constantly trigger and I found that git **push action** causing the continuous build of job one after another. If I remove the push code from pipeline script then job get trigger only 1st time due to pull request. How can I stop triggering of job continuously?(I also want to push the result data in compare branch.)